# Stackoverflow is not sending notification emails

Tags: email, notifications, stack-overflow, support, stack-exchange

I have an SO account and I have signed up using Google login.

Now earlier I posted a question, and I did not receive any email notification for when either someone commented on it or when someone answered it.

How can I enable email notifications?

Comment: i could not find any email notification settings in Preference in my profile page

Comment: You can't find them because there aren't any.

Comment: I think that the authenticated Stack Exchange API (2.1) can be used to track such events. You can write an application which notifies you of updates (or search on http://stackapps.com/. If you're lucky, someone else has already created such a thing).

Comment: So is not not sending them or you can't find where to enable them?

Answer (score 1):

Up near the top of the page is the Global Inbox. It looks like this:

[image]

Click on it to view any new notifications you have received. Near the bottom of your inbox there will be an "email settings" link, where you can get emails for new notifications.

[image]